# Adding an integer to a passed variable in a function web2py

Tags: web2py

I tried to do a calculation after passing a variable from **function one** to **function two** but I get an error. I try explain this below:

```
def one():
    a = 5
    return dict(a = a)

def two():
    b = request.vars['value']
    c = 3
    d = b - c
    return dict(b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

In the view **default/one.html** I have the following:

```
{{=A("link",_href=URL("two", vars=dict(value=a)))}}
```

Then, in the view **default/two.html** I have the following:

```
{{=d}}
```

At this point I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the request.vars dict, its keys are all strings, so you can not just use '-', try to int() the value and then compute:

```
def two():
    b = request.vars['value']
    c = 3
    num_b = 0
    changed_value = False # to see if value changed
    try:
      num_b = int(b)
      changed_value = True
    except ValueError, error:
      print error
    if changed_value == True:
      d = num_b - c
    else: # not changed add your own code to the logic
      # add your line
      pass
    return dict(b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. No more error msg. It almost works but it seems the num_b = 0 turns 5 into 0. So the the result of the calculation is -3 instead of 2.